# RTK query - how to refetch query during execution (race condition)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I use RTK query from redux-toolkit. I'm trying to solve race condition and I cannot find a built-in solution to refetch/cancel query while it is executing. I have 1 query (`useSomeQuery()`) and 1 mutation (`useSomeMutation()`). After mutation is done, query cache should be invalidated. To give some insight - user is changing form and by changing specific inputs (mutation) summary info is refreshed automatically.

Simple scenario that works:

1. Mutation is done (I use `invalidatesTags` to invalidate cache).
2. Query is automatically refetched.

Race condition scenario that doesn't work:

1. Mutation is done.
2. Query has started automatically to fetch data again (in progress).
3. Second mutation has started and finished before step no. 2 is completed.
4. Actual: the query has completed but is out of date according to my requirements, but RTK treats it as valid data. Expected: query is refetched.

I've tried to use `api.util.getRunningOperationPromise()` inside mutation using `onQueryStarted` to `abort()` but it seems that it only returns promise for the first load (not for updates).

Is there any built-in solution for that scenario?

Comment: I have same issue 
Did you figured out a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no good solution for this. Cancelling running queries was considered in the beginning, but could also lead to infinite loops etc., so the safest option was chosen for now.

If you have the drive to look further into this and maybe come up with an alternative solution, please open an issue on github :)

Comment: is there a way around after 1 year of the question date or is it the same status ?

Comment: @ArsanyBenyamine No.

Comment: @ArsanyBenyamine there is one ugly workaround to override onQueryStarted (in the mutation). You can collect timestamp with your own code (store/slice). Later on this information can be used inside component/view, with custom react hook. This custom hook should receive RTK query result (basically it is called right after RTK hook). Then you are able to compare RTK query result timestamp and your own collected timestamp and use .refetch() on RTK queryResult.

What I recommend is to migrate to react-query (TanStack Query), it solves that case by design (api call is canceled).

Comment: @Mad I haven't used react-query before. 
It's just I thought RTK-query is fully compatible with RTK. 
Not sure if this the case when using react-query with ReduxToolKit.
what do you think ?

Comment: @ArsanyBenyamine quoting from the website: "RTK Query is an optional addon included in the Redux Toolkit package". You can replace it and it's fine.